# On click to button render new Component if Form is Valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, render

Here is Link to my Code. I want to check if a form is valid and the user clicked to login button. It has to render a new Component on the screen showing that you are successfully logged In
https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-swartz-574vt?file=/src/Login.js